# How do you detect the colors of a traffic light? (exam question)

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, camera

I just took an exam where the question was: give three ways you can detect the colors of a traffic light given only a gray scale camera. You're allowed to use any optical devices.

We learned about Michelson interferometer's, and I was thinking that may be a way to detect colors, but I honestly blanked and had no idea how to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Colour wheel - a wheel with lots of different coloured filters.  The one that gives the brightest spot on the camera is the right one.
2. Prism - turn the light from the traffic light into a spectrum.  Scan the camera back and forth across the spectrum to find the peak.
3. Diffraction grating - as for prism.
4. Simple convex lens - a bit trickier - a simple glass lens suffers from chromatic aberration, or in other words the refractive index depends on the wavelength.  Adjust the lens to focus the light from the traffic light to give the best spot you can, and measure precisely what the focal length is.  Given the optical properties of the glass lens, you can determine the colour of the light.
5. Bits of coloured paper - illuminate the paper with the traffic light and look at the result through the camera.  The paper with the brightest illumination most closely matches the traffic light.

Comment: [says a resident of Massachusetts, USA]"Who cares? just floor it and make everyone else get out of the way"

Comment: Can you explain the prism more clearly please?

Comment: @gdagger It's a variation on the classic experiment of splitting light into a rainbow with a prism.  Use a narrow slit to take one beam of light from the traffic light.  Shine that beam into a prism.  Traditionally, you'd place a white screen to capture the rainbow produced.  Instead place the camera so that it can slide side-to-side on a rail, looking towards the prism.  That way you can slide it all the way from red to violet.  Slide it back and forth until you get the brightest output from the camera.  You'd need to calibrate the setup beforehand.

Comment: @SimonB, A practical spectrometer need not have any moving parts.  It could project an image of the "rainbow" onto the camera's sensor.  That way, a single snapshot would contain enough information to reconstruct the entire power spectrum of the light source.

Comment: @jameslarge True.  I think my version may be a bit over-complicated.